# Python code error related to lambda function

Tags: python-3.x

Python code error related to lambda function

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/abhisheksingh75/PycharmProjects/Practice_Machine_Learning/titanic_2.py", line 34, in <module>
    else x['Fare'], axis=1)
  File "C:\Users\abhisheksingh75\PycharmProjects\project_!\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4877, in apply
    ignore_failures=ignore_failures)
  File "C:\Users\abhisheksingh75\PycharmProjects\project_!\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4973, in _apply_standard
    results[i] = func(v)
  File "C:/Users/abhisheksingh75/PycharmProjects/Practice_Machine_Learning/titanic_2.py", line 33, in <lambda>
    fare_means[x['Pclass']] if pd.isnull(x['Fare'])
  File "C:\Users\abhisheksingh75\PycharmProjects\project_!\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2139, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_column(key)
  File "C:\Users\abhisheksingh75\PycharmProjects\project_!\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2146, in _getitem_column
    return self._get_item_cache(key)
  File "C:\Users\abhisheksingh75\PycharmProjects\project_!\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1842, in _get_item_cache
    values = self._data.get(item)
  File "C:\Users\abhisheksingh75\PycharmProjects\project_!\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 3843, in get
    loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
  File "C:\Users\abhisheksingh75\PycharmProjects\project_!\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2527, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 117, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 139, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1265, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1273, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: (3, 'occurred at index 152')
```

Process finished with exit code 1
-----------------------------------------------------------------code

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn import ensemble

df_titanic = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/abhisheksingh75/Downloads/train.csv')
df_titanic = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/abhisheksingh75/Downloads/test.csv')

#Drop column which are not useful from predictive prespective
df_titanic = df_titanic.drop(['Name', 'Ticket', 'Cabin'], axis=1)

#Fill null values in age column
age_mean = df_titanic['Age'].mean()
df_titanic['Age'] = df_titanic['Age'].fillna(age_mean)
#print(df_titanic.isna().any())

#fill null values in embarked column
Embarked_mode = (df_titanic['Embarked'].mode())[0][0]
df_titanic['Embarked'] = df_titanic['Embarked'].fillna(Embarked_mode)
#print(df_titanic.isna().any())

df_titanic['Gender'] = df_titanic['Sex'].map({'female':0, 'male':1}).astype(int)
df_titanic['Port'] = df_titanic['Embarked'].map({'C':1, 'S':2, 'Q':3}).astype(int)

df_titanic = df_titanic.drop(['Sex', 'Embarked'], axis=1)
cols = df_titanic.columns.tolist()
cols = [cols[1]] + cols[0:1] + cols[2:]

fare_means = df_titanic.pivot_table('Fare', index='Pclass', aggfunc='mean')
print(fare_means)

df_titanic['Fare'] = df_titanic[['Fare','Pclass']].apply(lambda x:
                             fare_means[x['Pclass']] if pd.isnull(x['Fare'])
                            else x['Fare'], axis=1)
```

Comment: Does `fare_means[3]` exist? What does this return?

Comment: when i  am printing fare_means only it returns            Fare
Pclass           
1       94.280297
2       22.202104
3       12.459678

Comment: but when i am trying to print fare_means[3] it's giving me same error

Comment: That's your problem.. your `lambda` function is trying to access a key which doesn't exist. Can't get much clearer.

Comment: pls help me i am new in python

Comment: I have *no idea* what this program is trying to do. If you don't understand the code you've written, I suggest you go through some tutorials and learn some basics, e.g. how `pd.DataFrame.apply` works / how to debug Python programs, etc. A code dump plus an unexplained error message together with "fix it!" is *not sufficient* for a SO question.

Comment: problem is solved i used ix function to access fare mean

Comment: Excellent. Care to share it with the community by posting it as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
df_predict['Fare'] = df_predict[['Fare', 'Pclass']].apply(lambda x:
                        fare_means**.ix[x**['Pclass']] if pd.isnull(x['Fare'])
                        else x['Fare'], axis=1)
```

I don't know why my code was not working before...but when i used fare_mean.ix()
function..it was able to locate element position